# Automate the boring stuff Chapter 4 character picture grid

Tags: python

After completing the practice problem of Chapter 4: Character Picture grid I decided to try to print out the inverse of the solution. After working through an IndexError and using a try, except loop to print out where my issue is I still don`t know how to fix my IndexError: list out of range

```
grid = [
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]


""" This part of the code prints correctly according to specifications 
from ATBS"""
for x in range(len(grid[0])):     # prints number of elements in list[0]
    for y in range(0, len(grid)): # prints number of lists in list
        print(grid[y][x], end='')
    print()

#This is my attempt at printing the inverse of the ATBS solution
for x in range(len(grid[0]), -1, -1):
    for y in range(len(grid)):
        try:
            print(grid[y][x], end='')
        except IndexError:
            print('Out of Range')
   print()
```

Expected:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
....O....
...OOO...
..OOOOO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OO.OO..
```

Actual:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
Out of Range
Out of Range
Out of Range
Out of Range
Out of Range
Out of Range
Out of Range
Out of Range
Out of Range

....O....
...OOO...
..OOOOO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OO.OO..
```

Comment: It might be helpful to print out the `y` and `x` when you get an `IndexError`.

Comment: I think your `range(len(grid[0]), -1, -1)` line is wrong.

Comment: Yes, if I would have printed out the y and x then I would have seen the problem started with x in the for loop being out of the index, the len(grid[0]) was 6 while [6] is not a valid list element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code `for i in range(6,-1,-1)`, you are setting up a start point of `6`, end point of `-1` with a step of `-1`. This will result in 7 numbers, counting down from 6 to 0.

The easy fix is to reduce your start point by 1:

```
for x in range(len(grid[0])-1, -1, -1):
    for y in range(len(grid)):
        try:
            print(grid[y][x], end='')
        except IndexError:
            print('Out of Range')
   print()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, If i would have printed a more in-depth error message with my x and y variables, I would have seen that my x variable was starting at [6] and the list only included [5].

Answer (score 0):

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]


def heart(list):
    for i in range(len(grid[0])):
        for j in range(len(grid)):
            print(grid[j][i],end=' ')
        print('')

    for i in range(len(grid[0])-1,-1,-1):
        for j in range(len(grid)):
            print(grid[j][i],end=' ')
        print('')

print(heart(grid))
```

## OUTPUT

```
. . O O . O O . . 
. O O O O O O O . 
. O O O O O O O . 
. . O O O O O . . 
. . . O O O . . . 
. . . . O . . . . 
. . . . O . . . . 
. . . O O O . . . 
. . O O O O O . . 
. O O O O O O O . 
. O O O O O O O . 
. . O O . O O . . 
None
```

At the last why this *'None'* is coming, I am not aware of it.
If any one knows please comment

Comment: You should ask this as a comment on the original question or ask it as a new question. You shouldn't be leaving questions in answers to another question.